# os.system() doesnt work [Ubuntu 16.04], [Python 3.5.2]

Tags: python, ubuntu, menu, operating-system

Down below is the code. When I run it in PyCharm (My Editor) everything works fine but when I run the python script in my Terminal and then type in the number, nothing happens except the "Finished!!" prints. Yes, I'm running the script with `sudo`.

```
# -*- coding: utf-8 -*-
#!usr/bin/python
import os
import time


print('==========================')
print('==========================')
print('1. Update System')
print('2. Check IP-Address')
print('3. Train')
print('==========================')
print('==========================')

Nummer = input('What do you want to do?: ')


def nummer1():
    if Nummer == '1':
        print('System-Update is starting...')
        time.sleep(2)
        os.system("gnome-terminal -e 'sudo apt-get update'")
nummer1()

def nummer2():
     if Nummer == '2':
        print('Checking IP-Address...')
        time.sleep(2)
        os.system("gnome-terminal -e 'sudo ifconfig'")
nummer2()

def nummer3():
    if Nummer == '3':
        os.system("gnome-terminal -e 'sudo apt-get install sl && sl'")
        time.sleep(1)
        print('Get ready...')
        time.sleep(2)
nummer3()
print('Finished!!')
```

Comment: My guess, you're running with Python 2 from the terminal and `input()` is evaluated to an integer so your `if` statements fail

Comment: Where can I see this and how can I change this?

Comment: Explicitly convert the input to `str` or an `int` and compare appropriately.

Comment: better yet: use `python3` on the terminal to just run the file with the same executable in both cases.

Comment: Use raw_input instead of input.

Answer (score 0):

Using **python 2** you are taking input as integer so its fail.

Change your input line:

```
Nummer = str(input('What do you want to do?: '))
```

OR

```
Nummer = raw_input('What do you want to do?: ')
```

But if you run your code like this

> python3 fileName.py

It will works.